# C++ temporary object references

Tags: c++, stdtuple

Assuming `MyClass` has an implicit constructor that takes an `int` as an argument, why is there a difference between `MyClass` being explicitly constructed vs. implicitly done so in terms of when the temporary gets destroyed? In one case it results in a dangling reference while in another it does not.

```
template <typename T>
void f(const T &x) {
   cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
}

int main()
{
   f(std::tuple<const MyClass &>(10));
   cout << "---------------\n";
   f(std::tuple<const MyClass &>(MyClass{}));
}
```

Output:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int)
MyClass::~MyClass()
void f(const T&) [with T = std::tuple<const MyClass&>]
---------------
MyClass::MyClass()
void f(const T&) [with T = std::tuple<const MyClass&>]
MyClass::~MyClass()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::tuple` has a templated constructor taking arbitrary types (overload (3) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple)). So, in the first case `int` is passed to `tuple` constructor, a temporary `MyClass` is constructed there, then destroyed when that constructor returns and before `f` is called.

In the second case, the `MyClass` temporary is constructed in `main`, and survives past the `f` call.